# What exactly does "smooth" mean in the sense of the Cayley-Salmon "27 Lines on Cubic" Theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I see that the Cayley-Salmon Theorem states that a smooth cubic surface over an algebraically closed field contains exactly 27 lines. But what exactly does "smooth" mean here? Alternatively, what would be an example of a homogeneous cubic polynomial in four variables which does not generate a "smooth" surface? My background is very elementary, and if answers could try to restrict the discussion to varieties and keep the scheme-theoretic language to a minimum, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a remark. I have never seen a proof of this fact in characteristic 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume varieties to be irreducible. One way to define smoothness is the following (for affine varieties, but you can define it similarly for projective varieties):

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be a variety and let $I(X) = (f_1,\dots,f_r) \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. A point $x \in X$ is smooth if $\text{rank}(J(a)) \geq n - \text{dim}(X) = \text{codim}(X)$, where $J(a) = \left( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(a)\right)_{i,j}$ denotes the Jacobian matrix. If every point $x \in X$ is smooth, we say that $X$ is smooth.

If you allow varieties to be reducible you need to replace $\text{dim}(X)$ in this definition. For more information check for example [this link](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014-c10.pdf).

You can take $X = V(xyz + xyw + xzw + yzw) \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ to get an example of a non-smooth cubic hypersurface with singular points $[1:0:0:0],\dots,[0:0:0:1] \in X$.